# Список вместо ячейки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Я делаю приложение для БД.Я хочу заменить ячейки с внешними ключами в датагриде на список объектов соответствующего класса. Например у библиотекарей заменить Id_Lib на db.Libs.А точнее даже выводить первые 2-3 поля каждого объекта Libs.И так с каждой таблицей. Я пробовал что-то написать в функции LibraryGrid_AutoGeneratingColumns, но ничего не получилось. Прикрепил скрин со структурой моей БД.

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Library.Models;

namespace Library
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private DataTable dataTable;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q;Initial Catalog=Library; Integrated Security=True";
            LibraryGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += LibraryGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;
        }

        private void LibraryView(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedTable = ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(); // Получаем имя выбранной таблицы
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + selectedTable;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                    dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    LibraryGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void AddObject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    // Set the SelectCommand property for dataAdapter
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content, connection);

                    dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter).GetUpdateCommand();
                    try
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        string messageBoxText = "Неправильно введено Id";
                        string caption = "Ошибка ввода"+Tables.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel;
                        MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
                        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
                    }
                  

                    RefreshData();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void UpdateObject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView selectedRow = LibraryGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

            if (selectedRow != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        // Set the SelectCommand property for dataAdapter
                        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content, connection);

                        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter).GetUpdateCommand();
                        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);

                        RefreshData();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void DeleteObject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView selectedRow = LibraryGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

            if (selectedRow != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        selectedRow.Row.Delete();

                        // Set the SelectCommand property for dataAdapter
                        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content, connection);

                        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter).GetUpdateCommand();
                        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);

                        RefreshData();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void RefreshData()
        {
            string selectedTable = ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + selectedTable;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                    dataTable.Clear();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    LibraryGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void LibraryGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            // Исключение Id
            if (e.PropertyName.EndsWith("Id"))
                e.Cancel = true;
            if (e.PropertyName.StartsWith("Id") && e.PropertyName.Length > 3)
            {
                using (LibraryContext db = new())
                {
                    switch (e.PropertyName.Substring(3))
                    {
                        case "Authors":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column.Header = "Authors"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column.ItemsSource = db.Authors;
                            column.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column;
                            break;
                        case "Books":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column1 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column1.Header = "Books"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column1.ItemsSource = db.Books;
                            column1.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column1;
                            break;
                        case "Categories":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column2 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column2.Header = "Categories"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column2.ItemsSource = db.Categories;
                            column2.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column2;
                            break;
                        case "Departments":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column3 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column3.Header = "Departments"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column3.ItemsSource = db.Departments;
                            column3.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column3;
                            break;
                        case "Faculties":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column4 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column4.Header = "Faculties"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column4.ItemsSource = db.Faculties;
                            column4.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column4;
                            break;
                        case "Groups":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column5 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column5.Header = "Groups"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column5.ItemsSource = db.Groups;
                            column5.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column5;
                            break;
                        case "Librarians":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column6 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column6.Header = "Librarians"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column6.ItemsSource = db.Librarians;
                            column6.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column6;
                            break;
                        case "Presses":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column7 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column7.Header = "Presses"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column7.ItemsSource = db.Presses;
                            column7.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column7;
                            break;
                        case "S_Cards":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column8 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column8.Header = "S_Cards"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column8.ItemsSource = db.SCards;
                            column8.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column8;
                            break;
                        case "Students":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column9 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column9.Header = "Students"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column9.ItemsSource = db.Students;
                            column9.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column9;
                            break;
                        case "T_Cards":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column10 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column10.Header = "T_Cards"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column10.ItemsSource = db.TCards;
                            column10.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column10;
                            break;
                        case "Teachers":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column11 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column11.Header = "Teachers"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column11.ItemsSource = db.Teachers;
                            column11.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column11;
                            break;
                        case "Themes":
                            DataGridComboBoxColumn column12 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
                            column12.Header = "Themes"; // Заголовок столбца
                            column12.ItemsSource = db.Themes;
                            column12.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName); // Привязка к свойству
                            e.Column = column12;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                    
            }

        }
        private void ExportObject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q; Initial Catalog=Library; Integrated Security=True");
            string path = "Library.bak";
            var query = $"BACKUP DATABASE {"Library"} TO DISK = N'{path}'   WITH FORMAT,\r\n   " +
                $"   MEDIANAME = 'SQLServerBackups',\r\n      NAME = 'Full Backup of SQLTestDB';";
            using var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        /* private void Import_Object(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             if (ImportButton.Text == "")
             {
                 string messageBoxText = "Имя файла не введено";
                 string caption = "Ошибка ввода";
                 MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel;

                 MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button);
             }
             else
             {
                 try
                 {
                     using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                     string dbName = "Library";
                     string path = import.Text;
                     var query = $"RESTORE DATABASE {dbName}  FROM DISK = N'{path}'";
                     using var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                     connection.Open();
                     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
                 catch (IOException)
                 {
                     string messageBoxText = "Такого файла не существует";
                     string caption = "Ошибка доступа";
                     MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel;

                     MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button);
                 }

             }

         }
        */

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Library.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Library"
        xmlns:SqlServer="clr-namespace:System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;assembly=EntityFramework.SqlServer"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="500" Width="800" ShowInTaskbar="False" Title="Библиотека" >
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox x:Name="Tables" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" SelectionChanged="LibraryView" 
                  Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Libs"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Librarians"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Groups"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Faculties"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Students"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="S_Cards"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Teachers"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="T_Cards"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Departments"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Books"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Authors"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Categories"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Presses"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Themes"/>
        </ComboBox>

        <DataGrid x:Name="LibraryGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

        </DataGrid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">
            <Button x:Name="AddButton" Content="Добавить" Click="AddObject" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="UpdateButton" Content="Изменить" Click="UpdateObject" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Content="Удалить" Click="DeleteObject" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="ExportButton" Content="Экспорт" Click="ExportObject" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: k]

Comment: А вся эта портянка кода с сырыми SQL-запросами и SqlConnection имеет какое-то отношение к сути вопроса?